# Share SparkContext across multiple files in same project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm new to Spark and Scala and wanted to know if I can share the same sparkContext that I create in my main function to read text files as RDDs in Scala files which are located in different packages.

Kindly let me know the best way to approach the same.

I would appreciate any help to get started with this. Thank you!

Comment: For newer Spark versions (2.0+) use `SparkSession` which have a `getOrCreate` method that makes sure only one instance is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. For instance, you can pass `sparkContext` just like any other variable.

```
package Y
import X
main() {
    val sc = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate().sparkContext
    X.read_files_method(sc)
}

// method in other package
package X
read_files_method(sc : SparkContext) {
    val rdd = sc.textFile(some_path)
    rdd.collect.foreach(println) // prints rdd data when run main method in package Y
}
```